# Linq List of Objects GroupBy Multiple Property Equality

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

I have a `List<ReportObject>` and want to be able to combine certain elements of the list into a single element based on the equality of certain properties from one element matching certain other properties from a second element in the list.  In this case, I want to update the first element with values from the second element and then return a list with only the collection of "first elements".

Perhaps GroupBy (or LINQ in general) isn't the right solution here, but it does seem like it would be a lot cleaner than doing a traditional `foreach` loop and newing up a second list.  What I want is something like this:

```
List<ReportObject> theList = new List<ReportObject>() 
                          { new ReportObject() { Property1 = "1", Property2 = "2" },
                            new ReportObject() { Property1 = "2", Property2 = "3" }
                            new ReportObject() { Property1 = "1", Property2 = "3" } };

List<ReportObject> newList = new List<ReportObject>();
for(int i = 0; i < theList.Count; i++)
{
    for(int j = i + 1; i < theList.Count; j++)
    {
       if (theList[i].Property1 == theList[j].Property2)
       {
           theList[i].Property2 = theList[j].Property2);
           newList.Add(theList[i]);

           theList.RemoveAt(j);
       }
    }
}

return newList;
```

Comment: What is your expected result for your example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, it's obviously that the `newList` will contain all items which have `Property1 = Property2`:

```
var newList = theList.SelectMany((x,i)=>
                                 theList.Where((y,j)=>j>i && y.Propery2 == x.Propery1)
                                        .Select(a=> new ReportObject{
                                                      Property1=x.Property1,
                                                      Property2=x.Property1
                                                      });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var newList = theList.GroupBy(x => x.Property1).Select(g => g.First()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like `theList.GroupBy(x => x.Property1, x => x.Property2);` will do what you want.